# Xcode regular expression replace for replace "<any number of whitespace>];"

Tags: regex, xcode, replace

I'm looking for a regex replace within Xcode that allows me to remove all whitespace & newlines before `];`

I have to admit I'm at odds with regex. I got as far as `\S(\s+)];` … but Xcode doesn't seem to find any occurances where the `];` is on a new line.

Here's two examples of what I want to fix:

```
[self methodWithBlock:^(){
} ];

[self methodWithBlock:^(){
} 

          ];
```

To this:

```
[self methodWithBlock:^(){
}];
```

Those badly formatted blocks were a result of learning uncrustify. ;)

Comment: Try using  \}(\s+)]; which should find the spaces between } and ]

Comment: I'm now trying with '\S(\s+)];' but Xcode doesn't find anything but ]; with leading spaces/tabs but no newlines. I found a mailing list entry from 2008 saying that Xcode can't do cross-line regex, is this still true?

Comment: BBEdit or TextWrangler is where I go for complex Regular Expression file work.

Answer (score 2):

When I encounter problems like this (i.e. the Xcode will not do regexes across multiple lines), I am glad that I can always pop out into a terminal and use the command line.

In your favorite text editor create the following... let's call it `ununcrustify.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$/ = undef; 
$file = <>;
$file =~ s/\}\s+\]/}]/g;
print $file;
```

Don't forget to make the file executable (`chmod o+x ununcrustify.pl`).

Now `./ununcrustify.pl filename.m` will spit out your processed file on stdout. Redirect it to a temp file. diff to make sure you're happy then replace the old file.

If you have a number of files to process I suspect this will be more efficient than the multi-step solution you proposed.

**How it works**

`$/ = undef;` undefines the end of line delimiter, which causes
`$file = <>;` to read the whole file into memory as one long string, allowing `$file =~ s/\}\s+\]/}]/g;` to operate on the entire file as one long string and finally `print $file;` prints all this goodness out.

Comment: There's just one issue: Terminal provides no preview of the changes. I wouldn't have run the regex search & replace (even with a staged git repo) before feeling 100% comfortable that the regex won't cause havok (or worse: subtle unnoticable code changes).

Comment: You can always do it to a temp dir and use filemerge to review the changes. Having said that I usually do this sort of thing on a clean, up-to-date checkout so that if I am suspicious/unhappy I can just blow the directory away, no harm, no foul. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Since Xcode can't do regex across multiple lines, I split this in several steps.

First using regex search & replace with `(\s+)];` I moved the ]; to the beginning of the line.

Then I used the Alt+Return trick in textual search to search for any ]; that had a newline right in front of it. After doing this search & replace three times all ]; were back at the end of the line they belonged to.